# Group by multiple columns while combining rows

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, aggregation

I have a table like this in ORACLE.

```
COUNTRY | AMOUNT  | MONTH
USA     | 100     | 1
USA     | 100     | 1
USA     | 100     | 2
FRA     | 100     | 1
ITA     | 100     | 1
ITA     | 100     | 2
FRA     | 100     | 2
```

And I need to get as a result a table like this. Grouping the rows by the month and combining certain countries (In this example if the country is FRA or ITA it will be change for EUR).

```
COUNTRY | AMOUNT  | MONTH
USA     | 200     | 1
EUR     | 200     | 1
USA     | 100     | 2
EUR     | 200     | 2
```

What would it be the right approach for this?

Answer (score 1):

You want to aggregate the data, but using a `case` expression:

```
select (case when country in ('ITA', 'FRA') then 'EUR' else country end) as country,
       sum(amount), month
from t
group by (case when country in ('ITA', 'FRA') then 'EUR' else country end), month;
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6f648b/1) is a SQL Fiddle.

Comment: With this I'm getting this error ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression

Comment: @Tom . . . The query works.  I don't know why you would be getting such an error.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Decode` :

```
SELECT DECODE(COUNTRY,'USA',COUNTRY,'EUR') COUNTRY, SUM(AMOUNT) AMOUNT, MONTH
  FROM TAB
 GROUP BY DECODE(COUNTRY,'USA',COUNTRY,'EUR'), MONTH ;
```

[*SQL Fiddle Demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9fb69/1)

Comment: With this I'm getting this error ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression .

Comment: @Tom No, There should be no problem, and I'm showing it on the added demo.

Answer (score 1):

To complete the set of answers there is a hard way.

Create a reference table to map each country to a region

```
COUNTRY | REGION
USA     | USA
FRA     | EUR
ITA     | EUR
```

And now use this query to get results

```
select r.region, sum(amount), month
from country c inner join region r
  on c.country = r.country
group by r.region, c.month
order by r.region, c.month;
```

Now you don't need to rewrite the query each time new country introduced. Just add it into the region table